# Restarting Apache after installing RSA Web Agent

Tags: apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, rsa, mediawiki, selinux

Good afternoon,

We are currently attempting to install the RSA Web agent on our Apache web server, but run into problems after installation, when restarting the web server.
The error we get is the following:

```
Mar 08 11:26:53 azu-noc-wiki02 httpd[452272]: httpd: Syntax error on line 364 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/rsawebagent/rsawebagent.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/rsawebagent/mod_rsawa_apache.so into >
Mar 08 11:26:53 azu-noc-wiki02 systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Looking at the Apache config file, we find the rsawebagent.conf linked:

```
# Supplemental configuration

# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
###### BEGIN_RSA_BLOCK
###### WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS BLOCK. ANYTHING ADDED WILL BE REMOVED BY
######          THE NEXT INSTALLATION OF RSA WEB AGENT
include /etc/httpd/rsawebagent/rsawebagent.conf
###### END_RSA_BLOCK
```

We've tried "OptionalInclude" as well, but apparently, it does give the same results...

Looking at /etc/httpd/rsawebagent/rsawebagent.conf, on line 6 we find:

```
# Load and add the web agent module in the configuration
LoadModule rsawebagent_module /etc/httpd/rsawebagent/mod_rsawa_apache.so
#
```

Since we are using SELinux, the output of sudo ls -rtlZ rsawebagent/ shows the following for all files, but mod_rsawa_apache.so in particular:

*-rwx------. 1 apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0    8352 Aug 18  2022 mod_rsawa_apache.so*

The command *sudo matchpathcon /etc/httpd/rsawebagent/* shows the following:

```
/etc/httpd/rsawebagent  system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0
```

The system, aside from the user apache does not seem to have access to the mod_rsawa_apache.so file.

What could keep the system from accessing mod_rsawa_apache.so?

Comment: RSA SecurID support asked to turn off SELinux. This does not change the behaviour of the HTTPD in a meaningful way.